How to add multiple Blazor web apps to existing Web API
I'm new to Blazor. I'm trying to understand how it works. We have multiple front-ends and an existing ASP.NET Core Web API (clean architecture).
What is the best way to add multiple Blazor web apps to an existing ASP.NET Core Web API ?

What do you mean by add Blazor web app to API ? Any number of Blazor (or any other apps) can call any API - there's no "adding to the API" or anything .....

I mean that i have a solution for the .net core api. How do i add blazor to the solutions? I have multiple frontend. Do i add multiple blazor web app projects to the solutions. Or do i have to add multiple blazor webassambly projects to the solutions? Blazor wil use the api to get data

You add a Blazor project (WASM or Server) just like you add any other project: File > New > Project in Visual Studio .......

Which is better to use: wasm or server?

It depends - what is your scenario? WASM: runs in browser, typically a tad faster (once loaded) - HOWEVER: initial load times higher (large initial download), and more effort to get at data and/or server resources; Server: runs on server, direct access to everything (database, file system etc.), no initial download time - BUT always needs a server connection, no support for offline operation. So: which one suits your needs better?

The data will always be delivered via the api. The frontend doesn't need database connections or filesystem. But i want the frontend to load fast

I'm not sure what you want but this repo of mine shows how to create a solution with different applications and backend APIs. https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.  Load the Weather solution.

Tnx Shaun Curtis for your reply and your repo. I will have a look at your repo tomorrow.

Also many tnx to Marc_s for his also helping me

blazor is designed for developers who are trying to use C# to replace js so that we can think it's used for frontend. Since you already have fronent apps and APIs to provide data, I'm afraid that you are trying to do a migration from other frontend apps or trying to start to use blazor to create new frontend apps. Blazor have web assembly and server before .net 8, and in .net 8, we have blazor web app to replace blazor server. Blazor web assembly can be recongized as similar to other SPA framework like React and Angular, blazor server/web app renders the html content in server side.


What is the best way to add multiple Blazor web apps to an existing ASP.NET Core Web API ?

As marc_s said, its better to create spreate blazor project inside the same solution to achieve your requirement.
Then these blazor projects could use httpclient to call the web api instead of merge all the client projects inside the same web api project which may caused hard to maintain the project later.
Besides, choosing which blazor project should also according to your actually requirement. More details about what's the difference and how to choose it, you could refer to this article.
For how to using the httpclient inside the blazor web app, I suggest you could refer to this article.

Tnx Brando for your reply.
